# Reason for coiling of telephone wires

Tags: electromagnetism

Why are telephone wires coiled ?Is it a non inductive winding,but then why is it coiled at all?

Answer (score 1):

No electrical reason.  The cord is coiled in order that the length of the wire is flexible, i.e., you can extend the cord by pulling and then it relaxes back to some initial short length when putting the handset back (without the problem of knots and there-like).

Comment: And there are plenty of 'industrial' and other phone with a liner uncoiled cord. No electrical issue.